# ui.bootstrap: simple popover is not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have vary simple page, but AngularJS-Bootstrap popover is not working: icon is displayed but when cursor moved over it nothing happens, no errors in f12 log. 
All 3 js files and 1 css files are in place.

Where is issue?

index.html page:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">        
</head>
<body>


<div class="a" >aaaaa</a>

<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"  style="font-size: 18px; max-width:10px; padding-top:0.6em;"  uib-popover="testing testing testing testing " popover-trigger="mouseenter" popover-append-to-body="true"></i>

</body>
</html>
```

app.js. file

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngTouch']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi try change your body tag to

```
<body ng-app="app">
```

Comment: No problem ;)   it happens